# OverlayFS - Multiple Lower Directories

Tags: overlayfs

One should be able to combine multiple lower directories in an OverlayFS mount by using a colon to separate them according to [this document](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt).

[image]

However this fails for me. For example if I setup with:

```
mkdir /tmp/data 
mkdir -p /tmp/storage/1448918558
mkdir /tmp/storage/1448918559 
mkdir /tmp/storage/1448918560
mkdir /tmp/workdir
```

And then run

```
sudo mount -t overlay overlay -o \
lowerdir=/tmp/storage/1448918559:/tmp/storage/1448918558,\
upperdir=/tmp/storage/1448918560,\
workdir=/tmp/workdir \
/tmp/data
```

I get the error message:

> mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on overlay,
>          missing codepage or helper program, or other error
>          (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
>          need a /sbin/mount. helper program)
>          In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
>          dmesg | tail  or so

However, if I remove either of the lower directories so there is only one in the mount command, it succeeds.

Am I doing something wrong or perhaps this functionality is not yet in the 3.19.0-33-generic kernel in Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've read on-line and tested, [overlayFS was renamed to overlay for the "newer" system (with workdir) to avoid conflicts](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ef94b1864d1ed5be54376404bb23d22ed0481feb). So one can now have overlayfs and overlay. However Ubuntu appears to only have the newer "overlay" system, but **only in [kernel 4.0 and later supports having multiple lower directories](http://windsock.io/the-overlay-filesystem/), and ubuntu 14.04 is only on kernel `3.19`.**

I've tested that the example given in the question **does work** in Ubuntu server 15.10 with the `4.2.0-19-generic` kernel.